# cs193p Assignment 2

Tags: objective-c

I'm studying the CS193P course on iTunes U & have a question related to Assignment #2 (Progammable Calculator).  I see other Q/A on this topic but none that directly address my issue.  Hope someone can help.

In the assignment, it calls for a method

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

which uses an NSDictionary (the immutable kind) as an argument.  The dictionary is to contain variable names (keys) and corresponding values (numbers of various types).  The values come from pressing one of 3 special keys called "Test 1," "Test 2" and "Test 3."  I can get the values into the dictionary the first time but cannot find a way to get them in there if the user presses a key for a 2nd or 3rd test.  I cannot seem to change the values in the dictionary or destroy the dictionary (dealloc and release don't work with ARC turned on in XCode 4.3/IOS 5) so I can create a new one.  I feel I must be missing something obvious but don't know what.  Any help on how I can do either of above would be appreciated.

(I realize I could use the mutable version of NSDictionary but the assignment specifically says use the immutable version - if I'm understanding it correctly).

Comment: What does your code currently look like? How does your `Test 1` work but `Test 2` doesn't? What's different between the two?

Comment: There is no difference between Test 1 & Test 2 except that they initiate the NSDictionary with different values (same keys).  A user can press the 3 test keys in any order - so if Test 1 is 1st it works but Test 2 does n't. If Test 2 is 1st it works but Test 1 does n't. The 2nd set of values don't get into the dictionary.  That's my problem.

Comment: Excellent clarification, thanks; though I'm afraid you're going to need to show more code to spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating an NSDictionary * object in your actions for those buttons. You can have one action that takes a sender or three actions, either will work. In that method/those methods you need to create an NSDictionary, you can alloc initWithObjectsAndKeys, or you can make as NSMutableDictionary and add to it. Then at the end you should pass those values to the method by calling `[CalculatorBrain descriptionOfProgram:self.brain.program usingVariableValues:variableValues];`

You're right to use the mutable version of the NSDictionary, but that's just the argument to your descriptionOfProgram:usingVariableValues: method. when you press the buttons you can create the Dictionary any way you want. Hope that helps, I just finished this assignment the other day so I'm happy to clarify.